# Google Analytics BigQuery Exit Not Matching Hit Number

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm currently working with GA's hit level data in BigQuery. I've noticed that hits.isExit is not always set to TRUE when the hits.hitNumber is not the highest in a given session. In fact the hit.isExit seems to be true several hits before the end of a session. Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: You can check hits.type - "EVENT" can't be an exit

Comment: sorry @MartinWeitzmann could you elaborate?

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann means that a hit of type _EVENT_ can't be an exit, only a hit of type _PAGE_ can. You see that "hits.isExit seems to be true several hits before the end of a session" because hits.isExit is set to true for the last pageview, which is not necessarily the last hit of the session because events may have been fired after the pageview.

Comment: @PolFerrando I see! This is occurring as someone goes into a checkout process and doesn't load the confirmation page (all the checkout hits are EVENT). This also means there is no transactionID event being sent to GA as they aren't loading the confirmation. I guess we need to figure out a way to stop this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments by Martin and Pol, the reason is because only PAGE hits can be exit hits.